# Correctly parsing json in swift 3 (array versus object)

Tags: json, swift, multidimensional-array

Take it easy on me as I'm extremely new to swift.  I am pulling data from an API that returns game information from a softball league.  Below is a sample of the JSON data:

```
    {
    "577": {
        "Away": "PUPPY MONKEY BABY",
        "Date": "March 20, 2017",
        "Day": "Monday",
        "GameID": "577",
        "Home": "JUSTIN SANE",
        "Score": "1-14",
        "Status": "Final",
        "Time": "7:00 PM"
    },
    "578": {
        "Away": "LAST CALL",
        "Date": "March 20, 2017",
        "Day": "Monday",
        "GameID": "578",
        "Home": "T-TOWN",
        "Score": "12-11",
        "Status": "Final",
        "Time": "6:00 PM"
    },
    "579": {
        "Away": "SHOCKERS",
        "Date": "March 20, 2017",
        "Day": "Monday",
        "GameID": "579",
        "Home": "TBD",
        "Score": "19-9",
        "Status": "Final",
        "Time": "8:00 PM"
    }
}
```

I'm trying to just print the Home team for each game as a start (so that I know I'm parsing the data correctly).  Below is my code.

```
let url = URL(string: "http://www.SOMEURL.org/REST/list_games")

let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
    if error != nil {
        print("ERROR")
    } else {
        if let content = data {
            do
            {
                let myJson = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as AnyObject
                //print(myJson)
                for game in myJson as! [AnyObject] {
                    print(game["Home"]!!)
                }

            } catch {
            }
        }
    }
}
task.resume()
```

Please help me out here.  Bonus points for being a little descriptive to help me understand what I'm doing wrong.  I believe that I am casting the array as a wrong type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your top-level object is a dictionary, rather than an array (which seemed to be what your code is assuming) - here's some code that should work for you:

> ```
> guard let url = URL(string: "http://www.SOMEURL.org/REST/list_games") else { return }
>
> let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
>
>     if error != nil {
>         print("ERROR")
>         return
>     }
>
>     do {
>         // Ensure there is data returned from the HTTP request
>         guard let data = data else { return }
>
>         // Obtain all of the JSON - where the key is something like "578" (a String); and
>         // the value is the dictionary of values (here given the type of 'AnyObject')
>         guard let myJSON = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) as? [String: AnyObject] else { return }
>
>         // Iterate through the keys of the dictionary, retrieving the associated 'values' 
>         // dictionary, and printing the value of 'Home'. 
>
>         // If the 'Home' key does not have an associated value for some reason, 
>         // print 'Unknown' instead.
>         for key in myJSON.keys {
>             guard let values = myJSON[key] as? [String : String] else { return }
>             print(values["Home"] ?? "Unknown")
>         }
>
>     }
>     catch {
>         print("An error occurred parsing the JSON")
>     }
> }
> task.resume()
> ```

A couple of things to note about this code:

a) I've updated to remove the use of `!`, which force-unwraps values and is generally not a good idea for json parsing in production-worthy code as it causes crashes. `guard let` is a nice (though verbose) alternative here.

b) The main difference between this and your code is that it progressively helps the compiler understand (through casting) what value types it should expect from the JSON.

c) The above can be tidied up to be less verbose, but hopefully works well as an illustration.

Overall, I'd recommend you cast an eye over [this](https://www.raywenderlich.com/150322/swift-json-tutorial-2) Ray Wenderlich tutorial for additional theory. Good luck !

Comment: Good one, in addition you could create an initialiser in your `LeagueResult` class that accepts a dictionary as a parameter, so that all the parsing logic can go in there.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!  This gets me a lot closer.  I've noticed it is only printing a few of the team names, instead of the entire list.  I did make one modification to your code.  It should be
print(values["Home"] ?? "Unknown") instead of
print(item["Home"] ?? "Unknown")

Comment: After more investigation, the guard statement was catching some issue in the data and the return was issues.

Comment: Cool - glad it helped ! Happy coding.